# Understanding origin of some ICMP error packets

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking

On my firewall/router Linux box I quite often see ICMP host/port unreachable errors like:

```
    Jan 10 10:11:56 localhost kernel: [80413.542607] firewall-invl: IN=wan OUT=
    MAC=c8:60:00:e1:0f:7c:00:01:5c:22:e0:c1:08:00 SRC=95.37.140.148 DST=my-public-ip 
    LEN=162 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=2053 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=1
    [SRC=my-public-ip DST=10.10.10.103 LEN=134 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=48 ID=0 DF 
     PROTO=UDP SPT=4608 8 DPT=13298 LEN=114 ]
```

Here, "my-public-ip" is the external dynamic IP assigned to iface "wan" by the ISP. Another iface, "br0", is connected to my 10.0.0.0/24 LAN.

If I am reading this correctly, then a host at 95.37.140.148 (Russia, mts-nn.ru) sends me an ICMP host-unreachable message in reply to one of LAN machine's request for a 10.10.10.103.

However this is very confusing for me, as in the FORWARD chain there is a rule which specifically blocks such requests (along with 192.168.0.0/16 and 172.16.0.0/12) from inside the LAN

```
    -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/8 -i br0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
```

For example, traceroute returns the correct "!H"

```
    $ traceroute 10.10.10.103
    traceroute to 10.10.10.103 (10.10.10.103), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
    1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  2.534 ms  2.496 ms  2.499 ms
    2  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  2.535 ms !H  2.617 ms !H  2.637 ms !H
```

So, how do I make sense of the above log entry?

Answer (score 1):

-A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/8 -i br0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable doesn't block host unreachable requests, it *generates* them in response to certain conditions.

Cheers,

Rob